# SQL Query subquery (second level)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that throws level error. It is a table that has the exchange rates in two directions

```
currency_from | currency_to | convertion rate
        ARS   |   USD       | 0.20
        USD   |   ARS       | 20.00
```

I want to get one of the games, for example, the one with the highest value

```
currency_from | currency_to | convertion rate
        USD   |   ARS       | 20.00
```

In the table, obviously, there are many combinations of different currencies and the following query would solve the problem, but it does not reach the second level

```
select *
from gl.gl_daily_rates gdr
where  gdr.conversion_date = to_date('20180301','YYYYMMDD')
and    gdr.conversion_rate = (select max(total.conversion_rate)
                              from   (select gdr2.conversion_rate
                                      from   gl.gl_daily_rates gdr2
                                      where  gdr2.conversion_date = gdr.conversion_date
                                      and    gdr2.from_currency   = gdr.from_currency
                                      and    gdr2.to_currency     = gdr.to_currency
                                      union all
                                      select gdr3.conversion_rate
                                      from   gl.gl_daily_rates gdr3
                                      where  gdr3.conversion_date = gdr.conversion_date
                                      and    gdr3.from_currency   = gdr.to_currency
                                      and    gdr3.to_currency     = gdr.from_currency
                                      ) total);
```

Does anyone think of how it can be solved? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions for this:

```
select *
from (select gdr.*,
             max(conversion_rate) over (partition by least(currency_from, currency_to), greatest(currency_from, currency_to) ) as max_cr
      from gl.gl_daily_rates gdr
      where gdr.conversion_date = to_date('20180301','YYYYMMDD') 
     ) gdr
where conversion_rate = max_cr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am missing something, but a much simpler solution would be:

```
SELECT *
  FROM gl.gl_daily_rates gdr
 WHERE     gdr.conversion_date = TO_DATE ('20180301', 'YYYYMMDD')
       AND conversion_rate =
           (SELECT MAX (conversion_rate)
              FROM gl.gl_daily_rates gdr
             WHERE gdr.conversion_date = TO_DATE ('20180301', 'YYYYMMDD'));
```

Comment: Hi, @brian-leaching, thanks...! but your solution will bring only one value, remember that we have several currencies and I need the maximum in both directions